# How to prove this function is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis

I've got a problem. I have to prove that the function is unbounded, I know that the this limit can show it. 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}2x\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) + \frac{2}{x} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)$$
But how to prove that? My idea is to find one subsequence (for example $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}}$ which one tends to $0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$) put into this limit and result will be equals to $\infty$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the taylor series of of $\sin(x)$, and $\cos(x)$ to show that this function is unbounded.

$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120} ...$$

$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24} ...$$

This gives us:

$$2x\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})=2x-\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{12x^7} ...$$

$$\frac{2}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})=\frac{2}{x^3}-\frac{1}{3x^7} + \frac{1}{60x^11} ...$$

Adding these up we get:

$$2x\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})+\frac{2}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})=2x+\frac{1}{x^3} ...$$

This tells us that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}2x\cos(\frac{1}{x^{2}}) + \frac{2}{x} \sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})=+\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}2x\cos(\frac{1}{x^{2}}) + \frac{2}{x} \sin(\frac{1}{x^{2}})=-\infty$$

Which means our function is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea shows the function is unbounded but does not show the limit equals to $\infty$ (also think $\frac{1}{\sqrt{0+2n\pi}})$.

Comment: Ok, you are right. If its enough to show that is unbounded, it is what i looked for.